# Environment variable not accessible with Python with sudo

Tags: python, linux, debian, environment-variables

I've got an issue with my python script

First, I defined an environment variable as

```
export TEST=test
```

My Python script is quite easy "test.py"

```
import os
print os.environ['TEST']
```

So when I run it with

```
~ $ python test.py
```

I've got the expected result `test` printed out. However, if I run the script with

```
~ $ sudo python test.py
```

I've got an `KeyError: 'TEST'` error.

What have I missed ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sudo runs with different environment.
To keep current environment use `-E` flag.

```
sudo -E python test.py

 -E, --preserve-env
             Indicates to the security policy that the user wishes to preserve their existing environment variables.  The security policy may return an error if the user does not have permission to
             preserve the environment.
```

Comment: Excellent ! Could you develop a little, I'm a newbie with Debian...

Comment: this worked for me.

Comment: If you need `PATH` you can use `sudo env "PATH=$PATH" python3 test.py` — certain env vars are not propagated even with `-E`